# Excel INDEX Match and TEXTJOIN Function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to combine INDEX-MATCH and TEXT join function

I have a company- ABC Ltd against which I have a job number as 15-SER-7170. I maintain a tab for the order details (called SERVICE ORDER LOG). It looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAgj0.jpg)
(A) **INVOICE DATE**.......(B) **S.O#**......(C) **CUSTOMER**.....(D) **ITEM**.....(E) **INVOICED AGAINST#**
06-JAN-2015...........15-SER-7170.......ABC LTD..............FEEDER.................???..................

Now, for the order I have issued them multiple invoices and I maintain the invoice details on another tab (called INV LOG) which looks like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCNuK.jpg)
(COLUMN A) **INVOICE#**..........(B) **ISSUED DATE**..........(C) **S.O.#**        ..............(D) **CUSTOMER**

8122...................05-JAN-2015..................15-SER-7170..........ABC LTD

8123...................15-JAN-2015..................15-SER-7170..........ABC LTD

8124...................17-FEB-2015..................15-SER-7170..........ABC LTD

8125...................25-FEB-2015..................15-SER-7170..........ABC LTD

8126...................04-FEB-2015..................14-SER-7158..........ROPE LTD

8132...................25-MAR-2015..................15-PRO7-497.........DANUE LTD

8133...................30-MAR-2015..................15-PRO7-495.........OPTRA LTD

8135...................26-MAR-2015..................15-SER-7170..........ABC LTD

8136...................30-MAR-2015..................15-SER-7170..........ABC LTD

I am trying to input the **invoice**# from INV LOG tab to **INVOICED AGAINST#** on the SERVICE ORDER tab. The formula I have used is 
=IFERROR(INDEX('INV LOG'!$C$3:$C$11,MATCH('SERVICE ORDER LOG'!B3,'INV LOG'!$E$3:$E$11,0)),"Not invoiced"). 
However it give me only one value as 8122.

Hence I tried to combine TEXTJOIN FUNCTION to it AND TRIED USING THE FORMULA AS:
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF('INV LOG'!E3:E11='SERVICE ORDER LOG'!B3,'INV LOG'!C3:C11),IFERROR(INDEX('INV LOG'!$C$3:$C$11,MATCH('SERVICE ORDER LOG'!B3,'INV LOG'!$E$3:$E$11,0)),"Not invoiced"))

But that returns all the invoice numbers as 8122, 8123, 8124, 8125, 8126, 8132, 8133, 8135, 8136, 8122 and not just the invoice numbers for ABC Ltd. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: does your version have FILTER()?

Answer (score 0):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula FILTER:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER('INV LOG'!C3:C11,'INV LOG'!E3:E11='SERVICE ORDER LOG'!B3,"Not invoiced"))
```

If not use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF('INV LOG'!E3:E11='SERVICE ORDER LOG'!B3,'INV LOG'!C3:C11,""))
```

This will need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

The drawback to the second is that it will return a blank cell if no matches.  If the `Not Invoiced` is a must then:

```
=IF(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF('INV LOG'!E3:E11='SERVICE ORDER LOG'!B3,'INV LOG'!C3:C11,""))<>"",TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF('INV LOG'!E3:E11='SERVICE ORDER LOG'!B3,'INV LOG'!C3:C11,"")),"Not invoiced")
```